# If else to switch case with different output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change this if else to a switch:

```
var check = $(".fav_c").children();

if ($(check).attr("data-user_id")){
    console.log('users');
}
else if ($(check).attr("data-company_id")){
    console.log('companies');
}
```

To this:

```
var check = $('.fav_c').children();
switch (check) {
  case $(check).attr('data-user_id') :
    console.log('users');
    break;
  case $(check).attr('data-company_id') :
    console.log('companies');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('default');
}
```

However this is not the equivalent, because i am getting always the default case.

What is wrong?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? If the children have both data-company_id and data-user_id you'll always hit the first case.

Comment: Is the change to a switch purely a cosmetic one, or do you need it for other reasons?

Comment: @mkaatman the html has data-company_id or data-user_id. not both

Comment: In a `switch` statement, `case XX` refers to the case in which check is equal to XX. Check is a jQuery Object, which is never equal to the string attributes you are looking for. I'd suggest sticking to the `if` statement.

Comment: @KjellIvar Because I have a wide range of possible cases. the example is simplistic.

Comment: @XSFg in this case, I would suggest [mkaatman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843785/if-else-to-switch-case-with-diferent-output#answer-28843871). That way, you can just log `$(check).attr('data-category')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add `data-category` that was set to 'company' or 'user' and switch on that.

Comment: For rethinking the problem and finding a cleaner alternative, have my vote.

Answer (score 2):

Your two codes doesn't do the same thing.

You are changing from :

```
if ($(check).attr("data-user_id") == true)
```

to

```
switch (check) {
  case $(check).attr('data-user_id') :
```

which means :

```
if (check == $(check).attr("data-user_id"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`switch` is used to compare two values. It is not the equivalent of `if`, in your case.

Actually, your `switch` translated to `if` would be

```
var check = $('.fav_c').children();
if (check == $(check).attr('data-user_id') {
    console.log('users');
} else if (check == $(check).attr('data-company_id')) {
    console.log('companies');
} else {
    console.log('default');
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't make any sense.

**Workaround**

Maybe you could try this hack :

```
var check = $('.fav_c').children();
switch (true) {
  case !!$(check).attr('data-user_id') :
    console.log('users');
    break;
  case !!$(check).attr('data-company_id') :
    console.log('companies');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('default');
}
```

Notice the `!!` added in each case. They are here to force the value to be a `bool`.

This will translate (for the first case) to

```
true == !!$(check).attr('data-user_id')
```